# Unable to access object of other class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am accessing object of one class in the another class. But instance variable is Showing null.

This is my code.

```
fvcObj = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
NSLog(@"%@",fvcObj.user);
```

Which things to take care in declaring object of another class?
Thanks.

Comment: I think an iPhone Programming book might help.

Comment: Or more precisely objective-c programming book

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this on your own?

Comment: i defined property for the fvcObj. But when i tried to print fvcObj.user, it is showing me (null). Dont know what i did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PengOne has said it is a new instance of the class FirstViewController and it cannot hold the data which you have assinged to the "user" variable in FirstViewController class. I think you want to pass data from one view controller class to other. If so then declare a method in the class to which you want to send the data and call this method from the other class and pass the data as a parameter of the method.
Hope this might help u.
Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
fvcObj
```

is a new instance of FirstViewController, so my guess is that the user property has yet to be defined.

Comment: Yes. fvcObj is a object of class FirstViewController. Can you brief me?

Answer (score 0):

In header file (*.h) for example:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

{
    NSString *someString;
}

@end

@property (nonatomic,retain) someString;
```

In implementation file (*.m)

```
@synthesize someString
```

This create setter and getter for someString