# NSString returns (null) when accessing from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, class, nsstring

I have a problem accessing a `NSString` from another class because it always returns as `(null)`. Currently I have two view controllers, the first has users coordinates and the second has a `MKMapView` which show the current user position on a map with a pin. The problem is that I want the pin to show the coordinates of the user position in his subtitle but the value of `latitudeString` is always `(null)`, but only on the other `ViewController`, because on the first `latitudeString` show the latitude value correctly.

Here's the code:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString                          *latitudeString;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager                 *locationManager;

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    CLLocation          *newLocation;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    newLocation = [locations lastObject];

    self.latitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g\u00B0", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}

@end
```

**MapViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
{
    ViewController              *firstViewController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController                *firstViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView            *mapView;

@end
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface MapViewController ()
{

}

@end

@implementation MapViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
    self.mapView.userLocation.title = @"Posizione attuale";

    firstViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    self.mapView.userLocation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", firstViewController.latitudeString]; // Nil

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I feel that I have seen a similar topic lately.  I guess it's "Can't access to a NSString of another class."

Comment: Where have your `CLLocationManager` instance in the first view controller has been initialized and started updating locations?

Comment: You are allocating new instance of `ViewController`.

Comment: @ElTomato Yes, but in that question I have answered how to correctly access to the NSString, but now it returns a (null) value.

Comment: @Zen in the `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: But then your newly created view controller's view will never get loaded because you aren't doing anything with that new instance isn't it. So how will it behave like you are expecting it to?

Comment: Aluminum, I don't have a problem, but thanks for your explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to access object of other class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646432/unable-to-access-object-of-other-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the value of latitudeString only when you call

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

If you don't call that method after having created an instance of firstViewController, latitudeString will definitely be pointing to nil.

This method is a callBack from the locationManager. Try to overwrite init into the implementation of firstViewController as follows:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And make your firstViewController implementing the protocol "CLLocationManagerDelegate".

This way you should be able to start the locationManager and the delegate method should automatically be called. And as soon as the method is called the NSString will be setup as expected.

However I don't understand why do you want to create a new VC object this way? Are you going to presenting on screen later on?

Personally I would recommend having a separate class to manage the CLLocationManager implementing a singleton pattern - so that you can access the same instance of CLLocationManager from anywhere within your app. Hope this helps.

Comment: No because didUpdateLocations is a delegate callback. To allow this to be called you need to setup and start the locationManager in firstViewController. Somewhere you need to do this - I'll add the code in my answer as I can't write it here.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm not very practical and I still can't understand the problem here :-/

Comment: Thank your for the code you've posted :-), I'll try it now. I just want to display the same NSString value in a different ViewController "loading" the value from the NSString in the first ViewController.

Comment: Just to clarify. If you have already your firstViewController instantiated (e.g. via storyboard) - this way you're not going to refer to that same object. When you write firstViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init]; you create an new object.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are setting the value of latitudeString in the `locationManager: didUpdateLocations:` method call, but in your MapViewController, you haven't called that method since you created `firstViewController`.

Comment: Hello Enrico, how can I call that method in the other viewController? Can you show me some code?

Comment: There are a few problems in the example that you showed us. We're not completely sure what you really want with that code, but I think `didUpdateLocations` is a delegate callback when you update location using `CLLocation`. The explanation is very lengthy, I think you should read up on CLLocation and see some sample code in other places first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing, that declare a NSString variable in `.pch` file so that it will declare globally and can be accessible from any class. then  in **ViewController.m** you change below :

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

{
newLocation = [locations lastObject];

self.latitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g\u00B0", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
string_declare_in_pch=self.latitudeString; // new line

}
```

and in **MapViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
self.mapView.userLocation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", string_declare_in_pch]; // new 
}
```

I hope it will work for you. let me know if any clarification u need..